# how to convert observable to array ? angular4

Tags: angular, typescript

post has a type observable not array , I need a help

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [tour] and [ask]. Also, please do not post your code as an image, as this is causing a great number of drawbacks. Instead copy and paste the code into your question, and format it as such (using the corresponding 'code' button or Ctrl+K) . Same remark applies for error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the async pipe

```
<div *ngIf="(posts | async).length > 0"></div>
```

to get the values for the current emit of your Observable.

Comment: Then i'd be happy if you accept the answer @theRealjen :)

Answer (score 0):

Would like to improve previous ans..
async pipe itself check for null or undefined value therefore no need to check .length>0 . So improved answer would be

```
*ngIf="(post | async)"
```

or another way is

```
*ngIf="post.value.length>0"
```

Hope this will help you :)